# Given a function over a real interval, find sub-interval of given length, whose average rate is at least the rate over the whole interval

Tags: calculus, functions

First post here.

I have a question inspired by real-world events.

Say I go for a timed 6-mile run at a variable speed. At the end of the run, the stopwatch shows I ran the 6 miles in 60 minutes. This is all I know about the course or trajectory of my run.

Must there then exist some stretch of my run where I ran 5 miles in 50 minutes or less? (More generally, $x$ miles in at most $10x$ minutes for any $0 < x < 6$). What about running $x$ miles in *exactly* $10x$ minutes? I can't think of an obvious counter-example. As $x$ approaches $0$, I think the "exact" version of my question approaches the mean value theorem, but I'm not sure if that insight is useful or even valid...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I ran the 6 miles in 60 minutes . . . Must there then exist some stretch of my run where I ran 5 miles in 50 minutes or less?

No. As a counterexample, you may have ran the first 3 miles in the first minute and the second 3 miles in the last minute.

(Of course, I'm assuming we're ignoring the physical constraints of the human body here.)